# fetch api local no funciona react redux

Tags: reactjs, fetch, redux, localhost, null

Estoy utilizando redux y react para un proyecto, la cuestión es que la accion getAllDogs deberia de hacer un solicitud a una api local que tengo en localhost:3001 (con morgan), y modificar el estado state.allDogs (un arreglo) con los datos de dicha api; el problema surge cuando me doy cuenta que en ningun momento se esta consumiendo la api o interactuando con ella ya que en un componente donde quiero mostrar los datos el estado se hace null porque no esta recibiendo nada por parte de fetch e incluso morgan no arroja nada introducir la descripción de la imagen aquíen la consola de que se haya hecho alguna consulta a la api

[image: accion que deberia modificar el estado state.allDogs con los datos de la api local]

Comment: [es.so] te da la facilidad de insertar el código _como texto, con formato_. Recuerda que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Describe además en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

quita el return, no lo necesitas ya que estas modificando el estado pasando el dispatch como parametro, y ademas en el payload cuando usas la funcion json deberias usar tambien await por la misma razon que la usas en el fetch.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]